onPress Event is not firing in expo react-native
I'm following the youtube tutorial react native full course (2:32:54) but when i code along the onPress event isnot firining for me, i asked in ai and search other stackoverflow post nothing working for me.my code is exactly same as instructor's. only diffrence i'm running in iOS simulator.can anyone help me on this?
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import React from "react";
import { Image, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";

export default function Introduction({ business }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          zIndex: 10,
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          width: "100%",
          padding: 20,
        }}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}>
          <Ionicons name="arrow-back-circle" size={40} color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}>
          <Ionicons name="heart-outline" size={40} color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: business?.imageUrl }}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: 340,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}




Most likely the status bar is getting in the way. Perhaps try adding <StatusBar hidden={true}/> and see how that goes?

@NickParsons where should i include this StatusBar component , i'm using expo sdk 50+?

Usually in your top-level component (eg: App), but for your example you can include it just under the first <View>

@NickParsons it worked.Thanks

Looks like the status bar from your phone is getting the way as your buttons are positioned at the top of your screen. You can hide it using StatusBar component to make your buttons work as expected:
...
import { Image, TouchableOpacity, View, StatusBar } from "react-native";

export default function Introduction({ business }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar hidden={true} />

      ...
    </View>
  );
}

